# Is ring R itself a finitely generated module over $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

It seems trivial that ring $R$ itself is a $R$-module. But then can we say R is finitely generated by multiplicative identity? That seems so trivial..

Comment: Yes, any ring is finitely generated over itself, $R1=R$.

Comment: And yes, it is trivial.

Comment: Is this proposition still correct if $R$ has no multiicative identity?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We can write $R = (1)$, but notice that it's not necessary that every ideal in $R$ is finitely generated:

Choose $R = k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ and let $I = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$. $R$ is finitely generated since $R = (1)$, but $I$ is not finitely generated.